# 3-variable inequality, how to prove it?

Tags: inequality, contest-math

This is a USAMO 1997 problem, given three positive variables $a$, $b$ and $c$, prove the following inequality:

$\frac{1}{a^3+b^3+abc}+\frac{1}{b^3+c^3+abc}+\frac{1}{c^3+a^3+abc}\leq\frac{1}{abc}$

I've found a solution in the 'Secrets in Inequalities, vol. 1', but the author states the following which confuses me:

Notice that $a^3+b^3{\geq}ab(a+b)$ (this is clear) it follows:

$\frac{abc}{a^3+b^3+c^3}\leq\frac{abc}{ab(a+b)+abc}$

How can we claim that the above inequality holds? What sort of relation are $abc$ and $c^3$ in? The rest of the proof is easy, but I can't get my head around this part. I'd appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is just a typo?
It would have been like this:
$$\begin{split}
&\frac{1}{a^3+b^3+abc}+\frac{1}{b^3+c^3+abc}+\frac{1}{c^3+a^3+abc}\\
\leq& \frac{1}{ab(a+b)+abc}+\frac{1}{bc(b+c)+abc}+\frac{1}{ca(c+a)+abc}\\
=&\frac{a+b+c}{abc(a+b+c)}\\
=&\frac{1}{abc}.
\end{split}$$